# how to use Redemption 4.7 without outlook installed

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I'm working on a program that uses Redemption 4.7 to pull emails from an email archive. It works fine if Outlook is installed.

When I uninstall Outlook and install the [MapiCdo](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&displaylang=en), the program runs but the part where it pulls the emails using Redemption doesn't work.

On the [Redemption site](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) it says it should work as long as I have that Mapi installed.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT** I found the line of code where it fails:

```cs
_store = _session.LogonPstStore(pst, null, null, null, null);
```

This line throws an exception.

Comment: Maybe if you could also post the actual text of the exception? "Doesn't work" seldom satisfies w.r.t. trouble shooting... Also, a little more context (such as how you initialized the `RDOSession`) will probably help us help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a restriction such that the MAPI and CDO client libraries are unable to handle Unicode PST files. It is likely you are attempting to open a Unicode PST file in this case.

Comment: Can you give a code example of creating an email with Redemption (without outlook installed) ?